# Add and Remove Elements from XML - DOM Parser - Java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

### XML

```
<company> <employee>
<age> 12 </age>
  <name> name1</name>
</employee> 
 <employee>
 <age> 12 </age>
  <name> name1</name>
  <status>active</status>
</employee>

<employee>
 <age> 12 </age>
  <name> name1</name>
</employee></company>
```

Java Code:

```
employeeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");
     for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node employeeNode= nList.item(i);
            employeeList employeeList = nNode.getChildNodes();
            Node insertNode=null;
            System.out.println(" Processing the " + i + " Portlet Tag");
                //Inner Loop to Process each Portlet tags   
                 int employeeList_Count=employeeList.getLength();

                 for (int j = 0; j < employeeList_Count; j++) {
                      Node childNode = employeeList.item(j);


                      if( childNode.getNodeName()) == "status")  {
                               removeNode(nNode,childNode);      //   assume remove functionality perfectly works (actually it is!!)
                      }
                      if ( j == employeeList_Count - 2)  // goes into loop during last node
                      {

                          Element insertElement = (Element)nNode;

                          insertElement.insertBefore(employee_status_element,  insertElement.getFirstChild().getNextSibling());  //employee_status_element,   this is the element should be inserted in all employee tags


                           doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
                           updateXml2File(doc, xmlDTDPath , outputFile);    // functionality to write the xml into file
                      }

                }



          }
```

Every time i run this code,  only the last employee (out of 3) gets updated with element "status"  ...

this is out the output is like

first loop completes
      tag is in the first employee tag   .. it pushed to second during second loop. finally only last element has the status element.

really strage... really appreciate your guidance.

Comment: unrelated, but.. you are missing your closing tag for company. and why do you subtract 4 from employeeList_Count?

Comment: I can't make sense of the routine you've written. I'd suggest you step through it with a debugger and see what's happening.

Comment: i still need to figure why i added -4 because , count leads to null pointer exception.  it includes the node which is null.     company tag closure does not related to this issue.. but let me correct it...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue.  It was silly but got stricked later after starrring the code for few hours.

Logic was like this before

```
Create Element
  Loop for Multiple Employees
        Attach/Append the Element to Employees
```

Issue: Element attached only to the last employee node in the loop.

Cause:  Since I created only one Element before loop.. i cannot attach it to multiple  Employee Nodes

Solution Worked:

Now i move the element creating into the loop then it started worked.

```
  Loop for Multiple Employees
        Create Element   
        Attach/Append the Element to Employees
```

My Question and code was little messy, i tried to correct it as much as possible to make it simple but not able to...  thanks every one who tried to resolve this one.